# Permission denied to exec suexec

Tags: git, gitolite, suexec

---

I'm working with two servers, one for *testing* and one *productive*. I'm configuring gitolite to work with http protocol (ssh protocol is also working). I've follow the instructions from this page http://gitolite.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html

In my *testing server* everything worked perfect, I'm able to clone a repo with `git clone http://user:password@testing.server/gitolite/repo.git`. Then, I copied everything from my *testing server* to my *productive server*, so all configurations (to make gitolite work with http) are exactly the same. But when I run `git clone http://user:password@productive.server/gitolite/repo.git` I get `fatal: unable to access http://user:password@productive.server/gitolite/repo.git: The requested URL returned error: 500`

I've checked logs, and *suexec log* is not generated, only error_log and it shows

> [Thu Apr 30 11:19:32 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/usr/sbin/suexec' failed
>   [Thu Apr 30 11:19:32 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Premature end of script headers: gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh

According to this, *suexec_log* is not generated because *suexec* never run. The second line of error is generated for the same reason. So the problem here is the first error, but I don´t know what **permission** is missing. I've compared all files and permissions between both servers and they are equal.

I've googled, but none of the solutions worked for me. BTW, *SElinux* is disabled in both servers.

Can ay one help me?, Thanks

*Edit 1: Add requested info*

**user/group for gitolite:** repository/repository

**folder containing gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh:** /var/www/bin
**permissions for bin folder:** 0755
**owner/group for bin folder:** repository/repository

**permissions for gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh:** 0700
**owner/group for gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh:** repository/repository

**gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh content**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Suexec wrapper for gitolite-shell
#

 export GIT_PROJECT_ROOT="/home/repository/repositories"
 export GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME="/home/repository"

 exec ${GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME}/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell
```

Comment: What are the permissions/ownership for gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh and the folder it's in? Can you include the content of your wrapper script?

Comment: @thylacine222 I've edited my question adding the info you've requested

Comment: What happens when you run `su -c '/var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh' - repository`?

Comment: I got `FATAL: who the *heck* are you?` as response

Comment: Hm, that looks right.

can you compare the permissions on /usr/sbin/suexec on your two boxes?

Comment: both machines have the same permissions and owner/group for suexec:   permissions `-r-s--x---`   owner/group `root/apache`

Comment: I've discovered the problem. It's an internal network issue, ports are blocked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my last comment, it was an internal network issue with that machine.

Now I've installed and configured git/gitolite trough ssh and http on another machine and everything works perfect, following the instructions from the gitolite website. I had just one little problem and I solved it by changing the configuration of SElinux from **enforced** to **permissive** mode (execute `setenforce 0` from command line)